# sql query with left join to get first names

Tags: php, mysql

:)

I have two tables:

tbl_user

```
ID  | firstname
1   | Max
2   | Jule
```

tbl_room

```
ID | userA | userB
1  |   1   |   2
```

I am user Max with ID 1 -> the ID is stored in a session variable.
I would like to know, where is in the same room like me and show his / her first name

I tried this:

```
$_SESSION['userID'] = 1; //Get from mysql database

$sql = "SELECT tbl_room.*, tbl_user.fistname AS firstname FROM `tbl_room` 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_user` ON tbl_room.userA = tbl_user.ID
WHERE `userA` = ".$_SESSION['userID']." OR `userB` = ".$_SESSION['userID']."";

$statement = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) { 
   echo $row->firstname;
}
```

For the user Max the result looks good. I get the result "Jule"
But the user Jule see Jule as a result, too.
For Jule the result have to be "Max".

Where is my fault ?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: you should also add  the code for fetch and manage the result  ..   of the query .. which db interface you are using??? PDO??

Comment: done ! :) please see post 1

Comment: Agreed with @jager91 Your table schema is bad and this is just the first of many issues you will run into as a result. The `tbl_room` should just be `room_id | user_id` where a room gets many records for each user occupying the room. Then this becomes trivial.

Comment: Uh I deleted my comment by mistake, you really should rearrange your db schema, right now when you will need to add 3rd user to the room you will need to modify the table structure what is a really bad solution, you should do like @JNevill said or add a foreign key with room id to the user table (and in this case rooms table should contains only id column)

Comment: okay I understood. but the problem is, that one user can be in many rooms at the same time. How should my structure looks like ?

Comment: Proper schema would be three tables. `tbl_users`, `tbl_user_rooms`, and `tbl_rooms`. Like `user_id, firstname, lastname`, `user_id, room_id`, and `room_id, room_size... whatever`. When a user enters a room they gain a record in `tbl_user_room`. That record is deleted when they leave the room. One user can be in many rooms. One room can have many users. This allows for infinite growth.

Comment: Note that a fistname is not a firstname